# Explanation and best practise around yarn - warning Integrity check: System parameters don't match

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, yarnpkg

When I was building and trying to run my docker image with a rubyonrails app, I was getting this error:

```
warning Integrity check: System parameters don't match 
error Integrity check failed 
error Found 1 errors.
```

I tried changing my Docker file with

```
RUN yarn install --check-files
```

But that didn't do anything.

I then just deleted the yarn.lock file and my container now runs.

I am guessing the issue is that rails was run locally on my laptop, and now it is trying to run the same yarn.lock file on another computer and the integrity check is failing?  Is this correct?

What should my dockerfile be doing?  Should I exclude the yarn.lock file from getting into my docker container in the first place?

Comment: did you try to run it from an IDE? I had a similar issue running it from RubyMine, just launching it from the command line worked, though.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, you will need to remove the node_modules folder and run the yarn install again. In your command line, follow these instructions:

1. Remove node_modules folder by typing `rm -rf node_modules`
2. Run `yarn install`
3. Run `rails webpacker:install`
4. Restart your command-line editor.
5. Be careful about the `NodeJS` version in your machine. It must be the same as the version in which the rails project was initialized. You can use [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) to manage the Node version.

Comment: Thanks! Additionally, as step 0, I needed to update yarn (https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/self-update/)

Answer (score 2):

Add "config.webpacker.check_yarn_integrity = false" in "development.rb" will solve the problem

Comment: This is not a solution. It will make the problem go away because it does not run the check anymore but that does not tell him why he is having this issue in the first place.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest not copying `yarn.lock` in the container. You can add `yarn.lock` in the `.dockerignore` which Docker will ignore the yarn.lock while building the image.

I had faced similar issues because, locally I run on macOS and containers are `alpine-based`, so we end up ignoring the `yarn.lock`

Comment: This is a really bad advice. You need to keep the lock file in check to make sure you are using the same versions for all of your dependencies in all the different environments you're running your project.