# 'Yarn: warning Integrity check: System parameters don't match' error. What exactly does it mean and how can I fix it?

Tags: node.js, ruby-on-rails, node-modules, yarnpkg

Last night I created a new project, started working on it no problems (migrations, rails server running, etc.) and today when I want to generate a new model via `rails g model model_name` I started getting the following Yarn warning:

```
warning Integrity check: System parameters don't match    

Your Yarn packages are out of date!
Please run `yarn install --check-files` to update.
```

Running the suggested command does nothing, as I get an "all up to date" success message but keep getting the error each time I try to generate the model.

I've [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62272104/explanation-and-best-practise-around-yarn-warning-integrity-check-system-para) that when working on a project I have to make sure I'm on the same node version that the project was started with, but switching between node versions via `nvm use *node version*` does not seem to be helping (pretty sure I started the project with v12 but I've tried them all from 12 til 16 while troubleshooting)

The troubleshooting I've tried over and over again to no success:

- Switch `node` version using `nvm use *node_version*`
- Delete `node_modules` folder and `yarn.lock` from project root
- Run `yarn install`
- Run `rails webpacker:install`
- Restart command line editor
- Attempt to generate model via `rails g model`
- Get the same error again
- Switch `node` version and attempt troubleshooting again

**What system parameters is the error referencing to?** How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Try to run `yarn install`, then `spring stop`, [works](https://makandracards.com/makandra/501795-yarn-if-integrity-check-won-t-let-you-start-rails-console) for me

Comment: It works for me too using Rails 5.2, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For all those people having issue in yarn packages installation. Please Do these step.

1. yarn cache clean
2. yarn --update-checksums
3. yarn

Comment: I bet this is really:
// yarn cache clean

// yarn --update-checksums

// yarn //

Not sure if the final yarn is required.